# How to take row out of listview and move to top of screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I am building an app, and i am trying to get a layout i want working.
What i need to do, is when a user clicks on a row in the listview, i want that row to rise above the rest of the listview (shadow, etc), and move to the top of the screen below the action bar.
At the same time, a sliding panel from the bottom of the screen will slide upwards, fill in the gap between the listview row, and the bottom of the screen.

I have got this sort of working by scrolling the listview so the row clicked moves to the top of the screen, but it is not ideal.

Is there any way that i can actually take the row out of the listview and do the aforementioned things?
I would also like to enlarge an icon, and change the text size in the view as well.

If someone could let me know if this is possible, and how i might go about it, i would much appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey :)

Comment: *"take row out of listview"* mean you want to remove that from listview ?

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain it very well. What i mean is i want to be able to move the listview row around the screen as if it wasnt in the listview. Thanks, Corey :)

Comment: hmm i think you need to use a custom viewgroup, rather than listview, because first of all, the views are attached to the adaterview-which is the parent, and they are obliged to respect their parent, so you can not adopt,them and use them for other stuff, but if you are talking about placing it at the top- then why dont you just change the z order of your adapter items.. or use `AdapterView.bringChildToFront("clicked view");` - this might not work..because the adpterview does not support some viewgroup functions..that's my thoughts..

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, its much appreciated. However I think you misunderatand what i am trying to do. I have achieved something similar to what i want by scrolling the listview up to make the row the first visible row in the listview, but it is not an ideal solution, as it doesnt work for the last few rows in the list. Here is a video of my activity showing row clicks at the moment https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_krkpxyd558V2IxOHFac1NtMEE/edit?usp=docslist_api I think this will demonstrate what i am trying to do better than i can with words. Thanks again for your time. Corey :)

Comment: @Fishingfon are you able to achieve this.